# i have data like this i want to order by both the dates how can i do that

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

| row_number | date_TY | date_LY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/6/2019 | 1/9/2018 |
| 2 | 1/7/2019 | 1/10/2018 |
| 3 | 1/8/2019 | 1/8/2018 |

my final output should look like this

| row_number | date_TY | date_LY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/6/2019 | 1/8/2018 |
| 2 | 1/7/2019 | 1/9/2018 |
| 3 | 1/8/2019 | 1/10/2018 |

two dates must be ordered in asc order

Comment: can you clarify what is the data type for `date_TY ` and `date_LY` columns? DATE, STRING or something else? Also - what is the motivation behind this ordering. Most likely you plan to use it as an intermediate result for producing final output. In this case - above question is strong signal that something wrong in how you try to approach this. don't get this wrong - just trying to get to the substance of your issue vs. answering what does not make much sense from sql point of view. Unless this is just simple homework :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a very SQL-ish approach.  In general, rows in tables represent something, not columns.

That said, you can do this using `row_number()` and aggregation or `join`:

```
select max(date_ty) as date_ty, max(date_ly) as date_ly
from ((select date_ty, null as date_ly,
              row_number() over (order by date_ty) as seqnum
       from t
      ) union all
      (select null, date_ly,
              row_number() over (order by date_ly) as seqnum
       from t
      )
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

The `join` solution is:

```
select t.date_ty, l.date_ly
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date_ty) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t join 
     (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date_ly) as seqnum
      from t
     ) l
     on t.seqnum = l.seqnum;
```